# Подсказка поиска, как в Google

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли в Qt метод для текстовой строки с помощью которой можно создать подсказки, например в поиске (как в Google, когда начинаешь печатать, а он уже выводит подсказки)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Qt обозначенный функционал реализуется при помощи `QCompleter`. Источником данных может служить как обычный список строк, так и модель.

Какой-либо сторонний сервис также может быть подключен, однако по вполне понятной причине реализация самого подключения отдаётся на откуп разработчику приложения.

Пример использования `QCompleter` из справки Qt:

```
QStringList wordList;
wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta";

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

Как только пользователь программы начнёт вносить текст в поле ввода, появится список из возможных вариантов.

Comment: Не знал, благодарствую вместе с создателем вопроса

Comment: @RomanNovoselov , взаимно, не знал про гуглоапи.

Comment: Да там чего только нет - хоть название книг или авторов например Google Books APIs https://developers.google.com/books/

https://habrahabr.ru/post/243853/

Answer (score 2):

Это не метод, а отдельный функционал.

Для начала у тебя должно быть "место" откуда брать "подсказки"

Объясню на примере: 
Например тебе нудно "дописывать" название города по введеный нескольким буквам

В качасте "хранилища подсказок" можно использовать [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?hl=ru#place_autocomplete_requests)
То есть пользователь вводит несколько букв, делаешь реквест к АПИ и полученный результат (набор мест выводишь в комбобокс). Опять же в качестве хранилища можно использовать свой словарь, главное чтобы был метод возвращающий набор строк (например по регулярке).